# Разъясните, пожалуйста кусок кода

Tags: java, enum

```
  public int[][] matrix;
 game.setCellValueEx((int)x+h, (int)y+i,Color.values()[matrix[i][h]],"");
```

не понятно что делает кусок 
Color.values()[matrix[i][h]]
Color этоперечисление строк, аргумент метода Color, что делает такая запись?Разъясните, спасибо!

Comment: Обращение к элементу с номером matrix[i][h]

Comment: почему такой синтаксис? Я не где такого не видел. Как это пошагово получается? Объясните, пожалуйста

Comment: Если Color.values() возвращает массив, то сразу после закрывающих скобок можно открыть квадратные - Color.values()[] - и и взять элемент по индексу matrix[i][h]. С синтаксисом всё хорошо!

Comment: скорей всего Color.values() возвращает тип этих самых values, пригодных для работы с [matrix[i][h]] в контексте game.setCellValueEx...

Comment: Спасибо, стало более понятно, тоесть Color.values() дает нам Color[],так как метод values() дает массив перечеслений  и далее идет обращение к элементу Color[matrix[i][h]], только вот matrix[i][h] то двумерный массив. Я полагал, только к порядковому номера массива можно обращаться, а тут как?

Comment: matrix содержит порядковые номера применимые к Color.values()